# Can't find circuit example for a solenoid valve 2W025-08

Tags: arduino, solenoid-valve

I recently bought [this](https://eu.banggood.com/fr/Wholesale-Warehouse-14-inch-Electric-Solenoid-Valve-For-Water-Air-Gas-Diesel-12V-DC-wp-Eu-978719.html) solenoid valve for an Arduino project where I need to flow liquid between 50 and 100 degrees Celsius.

I didn't find a circuit example or a technical sheet specific to this component. Based on a circuit I found for a different solenoid valve, I know I need a transistor and a rectifier diode in order to make it work but I'm not sure if I can use the very same components : A TIP120 Darlington Transistor and a 1N4001 Diode ( [from this circuit example](http://www.bc-robotics.com/tutorials/controlling-a-solenoid-valve-with-arduino/) ).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to find reliable [information](http://www.gasgoo.com/showroom/import_10062308404296/auto-products/1164397.html) on this valve but it seems the power of this one is 8VA, which means less than 1A DC. Take it with a huge grain of salt however. A measurement is way better than any wild guess though. If the valve current is confirmed, the [TIP120](https://www.astuces-pratiques.fr/electronique/le-transistor-tip120-et-ses-equivalents) ([datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf) [EN]) is quite fit for the job. The freewheel diode should fit, too.